# Inconsistent data when passed to alert in SwiftUI list row button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using the new SwiftData introduced in ios 17 to create a list of sections and rows.
On passing the sorted item data to alert on clicking the button in first row of every section, the data is inconsistent.

`}).alert("Add Task - \(task.title)", isPresented: $showingSubtaskAlert) {`

When I'm opening a alert with the above code, the task data passed is not always the same as the row the button was clicked. Sometimes I get task data of different row.
Complete code block for reference. Please add any suggestions to try.

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
@Query(filter: #Predicate { $0.subtasks.count > 0 }, sort: \TaskData.createdOn, order: .forward) private var tasks: [TaskData]
@State private var selectedRow: (section: String, row: String) = ("","")

@State private var showingTaskAlert = false
@State private var taskTitle = ""
@State private var showingSubtaskAlert = false
@State private var subTaskTitle = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List() {
            ForEach(tasks) { task in
                Section() {
                    TaskRow(
                        title: task.title,
                        isSectionSelected: task.title == selectedRow.section,
                        onTap: {
                            selectedRow = (task.title, task.subtasks.first!.title)
                        },
                        onAddButtonTapped: {
                            showingSubtaskAlert = true
                        }).alert("Add Task - \(task.title)", isPresented: $showingSubtaskAlert) {
                            TextField("Title", text: $subTaskTitle)
                            Button("Done", action: {
                                let s = subTaskTitle.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                                var isNotEqual = true
                                for subtask in task.subtasks {
                                    if subtask.title == s {
                                        isNotEqual = false
                                        break
                                    }
                                }
                                if s != "" && isNotEqual {
                                    task.subtasks.append(TaskData(title: s))
                                    try? modelContext.save()
                                }
                                subTaskTitle = ""
                            })
                            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
                        }
                    ForEach(task.subtasks.sorted { $0.createdOn > $1.createdOn }) { subtask in
                        SubTaskRow(
                            title: subtask.title,
                            isSectionSelected: task.title == selectedRow.section,
                            isSelected: selectedRow == (task.title, subtask.title),
                            onTap: {
                                selectedRow = (task.title, subtask.title)
                            })
                    }
                }
            }
```